# Exception while build presto

Tags: java, maven, presto, trino

I am geeting following exception while build presto,

```
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.airlift.maven.plugins:sphinx-maven-plugin:2.0:generate (default) on project presto-docs: Failed to run the report: Sphinx report generation failed -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal io.airlift.maven.plugins:sphinx-maven-plugin:2.0:generate (default) on project presto-docs: Failed to run the report
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder$1.call(MultiThreadedBuilder.java:185)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder$1.call(MultiThreadedBuilder.java:181)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to run the report
    at io.airlift.maven.sphinx.SphinxMojo.execute(SphinxMojo.java:234)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.reporting.MavenReportException: Sphinx report generation failed
    at io.airlift.maven.sphinx.SphinxMojo.runForkedSphinx(SphinxMojo.java:405)
    at io.airlift.maven.sphinx.SphinxMojo.executeReport(SphinxMojo.java:246)
    at io.airlift.maven.sphinx.SphinxMojo.execute(SphinxMojo.java:231)
    ... 13 more
```

Guide me how to build presto without any exception.

Comment: Did you use mvnw https://github.com/prestodb/presto/blob/master/mvnw ?

Comment: This isn't really programming-related question. I'd suggest https://groups.google.com/d/forum/presto-users instead. Be sure to include some details, stacktrace alone is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can install python and later use the below commands to separately build presto-docs to know detailed error from sphinx, which will help to resolve the build error

```
pip2 install sphinx

make -C presto-docs clean html
```